# intermitten java slow query to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, performance, yslow

In my application server, which is written in JAVA, I have the following symptom:

Once or twice per hour, the query to MySQL is extremely slow (8-10s/query).

My server queries to 2 different database servers, and both of them have this symptom, but not at the same time.

To eliminate the cause of network, I run a network monitor, and it reports that the network between application server and database servers is good. Moreover, my app server has 4 threads, only 1 thread have slow query, the other 3 still query well.

On both DB servers, I set connection timeout to 10s, there are some queries which timeout (>10s), some queries not timeout but slow (query time longer than 1s, usually 8s-9s).

1 strange thing is, despite there are slow query on client side, there is no slow query log on database server side (I config slow query time is 1s).

Here is a piece of my code that I'm using to connect to DB:

```
    public boolean checkSession(String sessionId) {
    Connection conn = null;
    conn = getDBConnection();
    if(conn == null)
        return false;
    try {
        PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT uid FROM sessions WHERE sid=?");
        stm.setString(1, sessionId);
                    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
                        if(rs.getInt("uid") == tamtayId){
                            conn.close();
                            return true;
                        }    
        }
        conn.close();
        return false;
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return false;
}
public void setDbConfigString(String str){
    conStr = str;
}
public Connection getDBConnection(){
    Connection conn = null;
    try{
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conStr);
    }
    catch (Exception e)  {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
}
```

Comment: all of your code is correct. Has to be something with your sql server

Comment: Make sure `SELECT uid FROM sessions WHERE sid=?` uses an index to access the table. Check it with `EXPLAIN SELECT uid FROM sessions WHERE sid=?`

Comment: I wonder how the memory and garbage collection settings of your server are. I have that gut feeling that the "once or twice an hour" might just be a hefty garbage collection sweep going on. although the 4 thread test result would probably contradict that.

Comment: PS: the code has really poor form. You should really close the resultset and statement, even though the connection close -should- do it. a few extra lines of code and you're doing the right thing.

Comment: @HopeRunsDeep: I'm pretty sure that my MySQL servers are running well. I tested and bench-marked them before. To be more clear, on the same application server, I run a python script, which queries to MySQL servers 10 times per second (queries and then sleeps for 100ms), no python query takes more than 1s to complete (even in the time JAVA show slow query).

Comment: @akuzminsky: sure, I have index on the sid field. Moreover, the sessions table has only about 20.000 rows

Comment: @Gimby here are some information on my Application Server

I run application on an Esxi VM, which has 2 CPUs, 3GB RAM
`java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)`

JAVA start with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Xmx2048m
-Xms512m`

I monitor Application servers with Ganglia, when the slow query happens, no phenomenon on network, cpu & mem.

Normally, I config 2GB for JAVA, but it only uses about 900MB-1GB

Comment: One more thing: I use SmartfoxServer 2.8, community edition in my Application server. Slow queries happen in my SmartfoxExtension (check user sessions to let them in the game).

Comment: can we see your server settings or your web apps database config file

Comment: @HopeRunsDeep what do you mean by "server settings"? You want to see my Server (CPU, RAM) or my Application (JVM options...) settings? In addition, I have an application (game) server which is based on Smartfox, I don't have web apps

Comment: First use a connection pool, currently each time you need a connection a new connection is created and destroyed afterwards. You also leave the connection open in case of an exception. Ideally you should close the connection and resources in a finally block. I acutally doubt that the query is slow but that getting the connection is taking a while.

Answer (score 1):

You did not use a connection pool, so the java server will keep connecting and disconnecting mysql.
Are there many lines in the table? Is there some other thread will keep inserting?

Comment: My sessions table has about 20.000 - 30.000 rows

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest to use a proper JDBC Connection Pool instead of the `DriverManager`, the drawback of the latter is that it creates a new connection each time one is needed, there is no pooling.  Creating a connection with the database is, generally, a lengthy operation.

Next to that your code is flawed, imho, your connection remains open in case of an exception and you should close the `ResultSet` and `PreparedStatement` as well as the connection. Preferably in a `finally` block.

I suggest rewriting the code as follows.

```
public boolean checkSession(String sessionId) {
    Connection conn = getDBConnection()
    PreparedStatement stm = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    boolean val = false;
    try {
        if (conn != null) {
            stm = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT uid FROM sessions WHERE sid=?");
            stm.setString(1, sessionId);
            rs = stm.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){
                val = rs.getInt("uid") == tamtayId;
            }
       }
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {}
        }
        if (stm != null) {
            try {
                stm.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {}
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {}
        }
    }
    return val;
}

public void setDbConfigString(String str){
    conStr = str;
}

public Connection getDBConnection() throws SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection(conStr);
}
```

Instead of setting the `dbConfigString` you should set the `DataSource` ideally and use that for obtaining connections.

```
public void setDataSource(DataSource ds) {
    this.ds=ds;
}

public void getDBConnection() throws SQLException {
    return ds.getConnection();
}
```

That way you can inject a proper connection pool like [Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) or [HikariCP](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/).